# How can I go to specific frame in animation?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

In my game I've created a world view to let the player see progression from a level to another. What I've done is that I've made small "steppingstones", three between each level. So if I have three level, that 6 small dots between them.

What I've then done is created a sprite where frame 1 contains 1 dot, frame 2 contains 2 dots. Something like:

```
0 - - - 0 - - - 0
```

Where if the player has defeated level 1, it would look like:

```
0 - - - 0
```

So i have sliced my sprite up, and added a animation. By default it plays thru it again and again. I stopped this by setting the speed to 0.

The gameobject is named "leveldots_0", to it is a Animator with the controller "leveldots_0". I guess the animation is named "leveldots" as it is the asset with the play icon? I'm new to this...

So, in my camera (of all places) in my update method I want to control what frame of the dots. For instance, I know if player has defeated level 1, so I want to show the dots to level 2.

I thought I could grab the Animator and I would be happy:

```
Animator leveldots = GameObject.Find("leveldots_0").GetComponent<Animator>();
```

And thats okey, it gets boring when I try the next logic (???) step and get a hold of the animation itself:

```
leveldots.animation["leveldots"].time = 1.0f;
```

And there is where I get the error:

```
 There is no 'Animation' attached to the "leveldots_0" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
```

How can I fetch the animation, and go to a frame/time in the animation?

Comment: Because you are using animator, why not create 3 animations. "Anim 1" is only your "0" icon and use a bool to make a one-way transition to "Anim 2" that is your moving dots animation. Then set "Anim 2" transition to "Anim 3" with exit time condition.

Answer (score 0):

That error is saying that you don't have an animation component attach to your game object. You are using an Animator component. An Animator component is like a State Machine in which you can associate animations with certain parameters, and you can also make interpolations between animations.

Now, `leveldots.animation` is a reference to the Animation componenet of that object, not the Animator. You could simply change one componenet for the other, and use the same animation, then you could access trough that same code. Or you can learn how to use the Animator [here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation/animator-scripting)!

Comment: Do you mean I could call Animation instead? I understand that levedots.animation is not the animator, but how do I control the animation... by stopping and going to a certain frame?